# Automatically extract specific rectangle of an image

Tags: images, image-editing

I have like 50 screenshots from which I want to extract an rectangle, e.g. the one going from coordinates 100/100 to coordinates 400/400. How can I do that automatically? I mainly use Windows 10. Thanks for any hint on this!

Comment: When you say "extract" do you mean to copy that specific portion of the image into a new image?

Comment: If so, I believe IrfanView does this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Batch Conversion tool in IrfanView: http://www.irfanview.com/

Once you've installed the program and opened it, go to **File** > **Batch Conversion/Rename**.

Tick the checkbox **Use advanced options...** and then click **Advanced**.

Use the **Crop** section to set your parameters. They'll probably be X and Y positions of 100, and then width and height both set to 300 (which should take you to 400,400).

Press **OK**.

Now add the files you wish to process and choose your settings for naming, saving, etc, and then click **Start Batch** to process the files.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Imagemagick

```
magick mogrify -crop 640x480+50+100 *.png
```

where 50 and 100 = x and y offset; 640x480 = size of rectangle.

Thanks to the other replies!